# Get YouTube data and write it as list item

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to do a list of videos showing the title, link, image and the creator of the video :S

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$.getJSON('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/users/Username/uploads?alt=json-in-script&callback=?&max-results=12&start-index=1', function(data) {

$.each(data.feed.entry, function(i, item) {

var title = item['title']['$t'];
var video = item['id']['$t'];

video = video.replace('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/videos/','http://www.youtube.com/v/');  
videoID = video.replace('http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=',''); 

$('.allvideos').append('<a rel="shadowbox[video];height=390;width=640;" href="'+video+'" style="width:100%;display:block;"> '+title+'</a>');
Shadowbox.setup();
});

});


});
</script>
```

How can I do something like this?

```
<div class="allvideos">
<div class="video">
<img src="[VIDEO_ICON]" />
<a href="[VIDEO_URL]">
<span>{NAME_VIDEO}</span>
<span>{NAME_CREATOR}</span>
</a>
</div>
</div>
```

Thanks.

Comment: You should not construct the link by hand but instead look for a `feed.entry.item.link` with `rel=alternate` and `type=text/html`, and use its `href` attribute.  @Lachian-McDonald answer is on the right track. The native format of this json is actually an atom feed, so that's why it looks so ugly. Using these feeds is much easier in atom+xpath than json if you can manage it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have changed up the way you have it coded. http://jsfiddle.net/s6kNK/3/

The changes I made make it look nicer, and work. I could not get it to display the correct image, but I bet you can fix that.

Answer (score 1):

[Hopefully this JSFiddle will set you in the right direction](http://jsfiddle.net/MW3Hs/) (first time toying with the YouTube API).